# Let the Javascript file get data from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a small Chrome extension so I have to put JavaScript code to external file from HTML file,and I want to get innerHTML from HTML file to use in my JavaScript file but when I used document.getElementById(),it didn't work.Can anybody please help me what I'm wrong with?,or can I use other way to do that.I'll show my example beneath:

My manifest.json file:

```
"name": "Multi-video and Single-video tab",
 "description":"Extending videos vision - Create a new tab with many videos you chose",
"version": "2.0",
"background":{
"scripts": ["popup.js"]},
 "permissions": [
"activeTab",
"tabs",
"*://*/*",
"contextMenus"],
"manifest_version": 2
```

In my HTML file I have this code:

```
<p id="multivideo">abc</p>
```

And I use this code in my popup.js file to create an alert box(at the beginning of the file):

```
alert(document.getElementById("multivideo").innerHTML);
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: The question is unanswerable without an additional information: 1) where is that js code - popup, content script, background script? 2) post your manifest.json 3) be more specific where is that HTML file and how you access it from your code

Comment: Thank you,I've edited my question.

Comment: So where is that HTML file? How do you get/access it from your extension? Is it a webpage? Show the code.

Comment: The HTML file is just an additional file in my extension and I think it's nothing to show except the code above.

Comment: Oh sorry,I forgot to tell that in this HTML file I have a script card like that:<script src="popup.js"></script> and I put the JS code above in the beginning of file.Moreover,this HTML file is not a popup.

Comment: So you load `popup.js` as a *background* script (what a misleading naming!) and you also reference it in an obscure html? That's convoluted and weird. Once again: how you do read/access that html in your background script (popup.js)?

Comment: Do you want to access the currently opened webpage in the browser? Or do you read that HTML file into a variable?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your trying to get the element before it loads. try this:

```
       window.onload = function(){
       alert(document.getElementById("multivideo").innerHTML);
       };
```

Comment: The answer is incorrect and doesn't solve the problem, also note that the fastest gun in the West doesn't work in `google-chrome-extension` tag in most cases, it only creates an unnecessary infonoise and confuses the OP who is already confused due to having not read the basics like the extension architecture overview.